# How can HTML5-Video record the PTS code or Number of a paused frame to allow a subsequent viewer to jump to that exact frame?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-canvas, html5-video, frame-rate

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475835/html5-video-jump-to-a-specific-frame-rather-than-a-time-position-or-step-pause) that answers with 4 commercial players that implement frame-accurate seeking and I will investigate them, but we are trying to build a tool for labeling objects in a video and we need to know precisely the frame that they have labeled so a subsequent watcher can validate their label.

We ask the users to watch until they see our desired object.  Then pause the video and navigate to the "Best Frame".  We give them buttons to go back and forward (1 second/Average FPS) to go move one frame at a time (unless our video has dropped frames, then they must push those buttons once for each dropped frame.)

[Bonus question: can we tell if  gave us a new frame or just the same frame with an updated time-in-video?  If we got the same frame, we could loop until the first new frame so the user wouldn't have to keep pressing the key!]

When they arrive at the best frame, we can record the time of that frame, but we are finding that the time often comes back with different milliseconds each time someone tags the exact same frame.  So we can't reliably have a subsequent user seek the exact same frame to validate the first watcher's label.  We are using Canvas to allow the first user to draw a bounding box around our object of interest.  Yet we can't reliably redraw the bounding box if it's on the wrong frame as our objects move quickly.

Ideally, if it can't be a sequential frame number, can it be PTS code?  Is there any other way we can determine the precise frame each time?  We are building this for a controlled audience that we can train, so creative solutions are acceptable.

We are open to a "cheat" because we control each video in our workflow. If we can write "something" into the file that can be read by the HTML-Video, we could seek to the approximate time minus 0.5 seconds and then read the subsequent frames for "something" that can tell us we have an exact match.

Comment: If you are using fragmented MP4 you could set your encoder to output each second (of time) as a segment. Every video frame can be a packet with its own MOOF header and there'll be an opportunity to add your own custom data in that header. You'll have to write code that edits the bytes of each MOOF.. Playback would be through MediaSource Extensions, where you "feed" the video frames into the `<video>` element. Because you chose which bytes to feed, you can check the MOOF header part of a frame that was tagged by the user...

Comment: Basically .. **(1)** Your encoder outputs a frag-MP4 copy with each frame in a MOOF (check settings of encoder for how to do this). **(2)** You pass the bytes through some JS code you wrote to find each MOOF header and extend it bytes with entry for frame number or PTS... **(3)** On playback via MSE, you append each MOOF into video tag, and when a user marks on the video, you note the frame num/PTS of the currently appended MOOF. You check by checking for the custom bytes you added earlier (in JS code after encoding)...

Comment: PS: The point I wanted to say earlier is **how are you calculating frame number from video time**? In Chrome, by knowing the FPS, it's usually enough to calculate frame num from the `video.currentTime`... Did you ever test on a video with an SMPTE time code?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @VC.One, I am sending your suggestion to my coding team for their ideas.  As to your last question, we have tried various techniques to calculate frame number via FPS and time-in-video math, but they are all unreliable because the primary variable is time-in-video so converting to frame-number doesn't add value when we must talk to <video> in time units.

Comment: As for SMPTE time code, i understand from [Wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_timecode) that _italic_ In general, SMPTE timecode frame rate information is implicit, known from the rate of arrival of the timecode from the medium. It may also be specified in other metadata encoded in the medium. The interpretation of several bits, including the color framing and drop frame bits, depends on the underlying data rate. In particular, the drop frame bit is only valid for 29.97 and 30 frame/s. _italic_ So we can't read this info from the clip, so I don't see how its helpful.

Comment: Hi, let me clarify about SMPTE code in a video... I meant have you tried playing a video with a timecode as its pixels (eg: video of white text for clock digits on a black bkgrnd)? Then you can fine-tune your seeking math to land on the required frame. With those on-screen reference numbers being used to confirm the displayed current video frame.. Your team should know of FFmpeg and they can generate such a video with it. Then fine-tune their seeking math.

Comment: PS: Regarding _"We must talk to `<video>` in time units"_ Yes, but time is made of slices (frames) so you can seek to specific microseconds with `video.currentTime += offset;` where offset is 1/FPS. Try stepping through a video that shows frame numbers on-screen with this example app I made for a past client : [LUT Effect Previewer](https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vc1.clients.lutprev1/demo_lut_previewer_vc1_01.html). To step frame-by-frame you click the larger view (on the right) and use the keyboard's arrow keys (left/right arrow)... PPS: It was custom-made to run best on Chrome or Edge.